# Camel doesn't retrieve SQS messages attributes

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Here is the route:

```
from("aws-sqs://myQueue?accessKey=RAW(xxx)&secretKey=RAW(yyy)&deleteAfterRead=false")
.log("Attributes: ${header.CamelAwsSqsAttributes}")
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> messageAttributes = (Map<String, String>) exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelAwsSqsAttributes");
        ...
    }
});
```

The `.log()` shows an empty map as well as if I print `messageAttributes` from the processor.

I also tried with the header `"CamelAwsSqsMessageAttributes"` instead of `"CamelAwsSqsAttributes"` but still nothing.

I see the attributes from the `AWS` console though.
By the way I get the message body, and I use Camel 2.15

Comment: Just take a look at what other headers is there

Comment: I did already:  
breadcrumbId=xxx
CamelAwsSqsAttributes={}
CamelAwsSqsMD5OfBody=yyy
CamelAwsSqsMessageAttributes={}
CamelAwsSqsMessageId=zzz
CamelAwsSqsReceiptHandle=aaa (xxx, yyy, zzz and aaa are just replacements of course)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out, here is an example to get queue attributes and message attributes:

```
main.bind("sqsAttributeNames", Collections.singletonList("All"));
main.bind("sqsMessageAttributeNames", Collections.singletonList("All"));
```

Or add those objects to the registry if you don't use `org.apache.camel.main.Main`
Then:

```
from("aws-sqs://myQueue?accessKey=RAW(xxx)&secretKey=RAW(yyy)&deleteAfterRead=false&attributeNames=#sqsAttributeNames&messageAttributeNames=#sqsMessageAttributeNames")
```

Of course you can replace `Collections.singletonList("All")` with the list of attributes you need if you don't want all of them.

Comment: main.bind part needs to be add in producer or consumer?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. When I am using camel-aws 2.16.x and I have my endpoint configured as follow

```
from("aws-sqs://myQueue?...&messageAttributeNames=#sqsMsgAttributeNames")
    .to(...)
```

Then I have defined a Collection of String in my spring configuration file

```
@Bean
public Collection<String> sqsMsgAttributeNames() {
     return Arrays.asList("Attr1", "Attr2");
}
```

Above settings work fine but ever since I upgraded to camel-aws 2.17.3. It no longer works. As mentioned in [Camel SQS Component](http://camel.apache.org/aws-sqs.html), collection of string no longer will be supported for **messageAttributeNames** and it should be a String with attributes separated by comma.

> Note: The string containing attributes should not contain any white
>   spaces otherwise camel-aws component will only read the first
>   attribute. I went through the pain to debug on this. Besides, setting the 
>   attribute value to be "All" does not work for me, none of the message 
>   attributes will be read.

Below is the changes I made that allowed camel-aws's SqsConsumer to work again:

```
@Bean
public String sqsMsgAttributeNames() {
     return String.format("%s,%s", "Attr1", "Attr2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue of Camel. It can be the default behavior of `SQS` or `aws-java-sdk-core` library.
As a quick solution this `aws-sqs` URL can be used

```
aws-sqs://myQueue?<other attributes here>&attributeNames=All
```

Keep in mind that `localstack` can work well without `attributeNames` parameter, unlike SQS.

Comment: The accepted answer was given almost 6 years ago, but as of 2021 this newer one is really the best information.  The accepted answer requires you to make a code change, whereas this one just requires an update to your endpoint URI (which is probably being loaded from a config property anyway).

Comment: HOWEVER, I do think this answer might be incomplete.  It only mentions adding `attributeNames=All` to the endpoint URI, whereas in my testing I found that I also needed to add `messageAttributeNames=All` as well.